# angular rxjs: access parameter on http error inside pipe/concatMap?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I'm currently using pipe and concatMap to chain multiple http requests like this:

```
onErrorResumeNext(from(ids))
    .pipe(
        delay(10),
        concatMap(id => get(id))
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
        if (res = emptydata) return id
});
```

The get function handles building the query string from an array of ids and also contains retry and catchError.

Now, the problem is I need to access the same **id** parameter if I get no data on the response object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you need to access the `id` parameter?

Comment: After subscription. It's not really an http error because I do get a response. It's just an empty object. I have an if-else statement after subscription that can check for that. If true, I need to find which ID it was.

Comment: What do you mean by "after subscription?" You can't do anything after the subscription since it's asynchronous. You would have to handle it within the subscription callback.

Comment: Yes, the subscription callback once the response comes back. I've edited the question. I'm not sure if this might affect it, but the subscription happens in the component, however, the pipe is returned from a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concatMap` (and other higher order Observable operators) take an optional result selector function (*Note: this is deprecated*) that takes the output value and input value arguments. This allows you to pass both to the stream (for example as an array):

```
onErrorResumeNext(from(ids))
    .pipe(
        delay(10),
        concatMap(id => get(id), (res, id) => ([res, id]))
    )
    .subscribe(([res, id]) => {
        // note that `return` does nothing here
        if (res == emptydata) return id
});
```

If `get` is an Observable, you could also return `id` in the context where you have access to it:

```
concatMap(id => get(id).pipe(
  map(res => res != emptydata ? res : id)
)
```

If `get` is *not* an array, you can use an Observable creation function such as `from` to turn it into an array.

Comment: Will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that the result selector was deprecated on most operators since v5/v6. Please consider this in your answer.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I wasn't aware of the resultSelector deprecation; thank you for pointing that out. I don't know another way to handle this other than my other suggestion of working within the `concatMap` callback function context.

Comment: I read about the resultSelector and its deprecation. Did not really understood how/when to use it before. However, since it's working for me. I'd use it while I can.

Comment: @JignoAlfredVenezuela https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration explains how to migrate, and my second code example is specific to your case.

Comment: Thanks for link! Was actually looking for that. I got it working with the first example which was a great help since i also found out about concurrency.